# How to restart Redmine?

Tags: redmine, restart, reboot

I have a Redmine installed on CentOS without GUI.
I changed email configuration and a reboot is necessary.

How to restart redmine from command line?

Comment: Which application container do you use?
Apache/Passenger, Thin, Webrick...
And did you installed redmine from repository or manually?

Answer (score 29):

Restarting Apache (if you use passenger) sometimes does not make desired effect. You can restart Redmine with creating a file:

```
<redmineHomeDir>/tmp/restart.txt
```

with content "restart". Anytime you want to restart Redmine, just "**touch**" this file to change its **time-stamp**.

```
touch <redmineHomeDir>/tmp/restart.txt
```

Redmine will restart at the next page request.
This solution can be found on Redmine forums or user blogs (e.g. 
http://texdex.blogspot.com/2011/03/restarting-redmine-without-restarting.html)

Comment: Using Redmine via Helicon Zoo on IIS7 and this worked for me

Comment: That is an awesome tip :P

Comment: Redmine on Debian worked with `touch /usr/share/redmine/tmp/restart.txt`

Answer (score 7):

Depending on how you installed Redmine the restart will look differently. See the scenarios listed below:

**Apache/Passenger**
When installing using Passenger restarting *Apache* restarts *Redmine* as well. 
Example:

```
root@myserver:~# service httpd restart
```

**Bitnami**

```
root@myserver:~# service bitnami restart
```

**Others**

The rule of thumb is to restart the application container.
Since redmine runs in a container (ie. Passenger, Bitnami) *restarting the container* also restarts Redmine.

***Note:*** 
This issue has been discussed on the Redmine forum. In this thread you can see restart procedures for specific installations. Link: http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/6719?r=6789

Answer (score 5):

according to https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/nginx/restart_app.html
you can also restart the passenger applications through

```
passenger-config restart-app
```

Comment: That worked for me! (with `sudo` or better with proper user)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I wanted to update the answer a bit.

If it's a standalone version just do in `<RedmineHomeDir>` `touch tmp/restart.txt`

if it's in docker, a more elegant solution (especially if it's `sameersbn/docker-redmine`) would be to NOT restart the docker container alltogheter as you'll lose any settings done to the container, and just restart the unicorn running in supervizor!

In order to do this you have to run:

```
supervizorctl
restart unicorn
exit
```

This is usually the normal path to not lose aditional configurations done in the Docker Container.

Normally all settings should be done at the creation of a Docker Container, but some settings might be done as a 'hotfix' until a later deploy.

Comment: I believe the command should be supervisorctl

Answer (score 0):

If you know the PID of Redmine try to stop it with `kill -2 REDMINEPID` and start it again as normal. You should check it with `ps aux` before restarting.